# Comparing Factors of Order Exp[I*x]

Tags: list-manipulation, function-comparison

I hope you are doing well.

If I have expressions stored in a list such as this $ \{ f_1'(y)(ie^{i x}) , f_2'(y)(2ie^{2 i x}) \}$, is there any way for Mathematica to compare the $e^{m x i}$ terms and determine which is the higher order in $x$, then return the higher ordered expression in the list? When determining which is the higher order, Mathematica should disregard the functions in front of each term.

I naively asked this question here: [Limit at Infinity of Arbitrary Functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218584/limit-at-infinity-of-arbitrary-functions), forgetting I was working with complex exponentials. Finding the limit at infinity of the quotient of the expressions would have worked if they were normal exponentials and not complex exponentials.

Edit 1:
I have an initial idea which piggy backs off my limits at infinity idea.

```
list = {(f_{1}'(y)*e^{i x}, f_{2}'(y)*e^{2 i x}}};
Factor1 = list[[1]];
Factor2 = list[[2]];

Factor1temp = Simplify[Factor1]./ {I*x->x}
Factor2temp = Simplify[Factor2]./ {I*x->x}
```

This returns

```
e^x f_{1}'(y)
e^{2 i x} f_{2}'(y)
```

The first expression the $i x$ got replaced with just $x$ but the second expression the $2 i x$ did not get changed to $2 x$. I can change the `/. {I*x->x}` to `/. {2*I*x->x}` but is there a way to tell Mathematica to ignore the integers out front and just replace the $ix$ to $x$.

```
Factor2temp = Simplify[Factor2]./ {2*I*x->2x}
```

returns

```
2 i e^{2 x} f_{2}'(y)
```

In any case now that they are no longer complex exponentials I can compare the terms by taking their limit at infinity.

```
Limit[Factor1temp/Factor2temp, x -> \[Infinity]]
```

This returns 0, therefore Factor2 is the higher ordered term. This one however,

```
Limit[Factor2temp/Factor1temp, x -> \[Infinity]]
```

returns

```
((i \[Infinty]) f_2 '(y))/f_1 '(y)
```

instead of $\infty$. Is there a way to make Mathematica output $\infty$ instead of what's given. The $f$ functions here are arbitrary but finite so the returned answer should give $\infty$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: I apologize. I meant to say $x$ not $\theta$.

Comment: Your syntax seems a bit off. Please be careful with parentheses `()` and function arguments `[]`. Which ones do you mean?

Comment: This might become more comprehensible if you use Mathematica notation throughout. The mix of Mathematica and (unrendered) LaTeX is more than I can handle. Also a simple example of (Mathematica-format) input and desired output would be useful.

Comment: @Roman I will do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly. Assuming that you want the largest prefactor of $x$ in the exponent,

```
L = {f1'[y][I E^(I x)], f2'[y][2 I E^(2 I x)]};
MaximalBy[L, # /. _[_. E^(b_. x)] -> b/I &]

(*    {Derivative[1][f2][y][2 I E^(2 I x)]}    *)
```

or if your definitions (which are a bit unclear) are rather

```
L = {f1'[y] (I E^(I x)), f2'[y] (2 I E^(2 I x))};
MaximalBy[L, # /. _. E^(b_. x) -> b/I &]

(*    {2 I E^(2 I x) Derivative[1][f2][y]}    *)
```

(using [Default patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#17673))

### Update

A more stable version that works even for $e^{0 i x}$ terms is to use the [`Exponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html) function:

```
L = Table[c[m] E^(I m x), {m, -3, 0}]
(*    {E^(-3 I x) c[-3], E^(-2 I x) c[-2], E^(-I x) c[-1], c[0]}    *)

MaximalBy[L, Exponent[#, E^(I x)] &]
(*    {c[0]}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. If I may ask what you did there with the `# /. _. ` in the `'MaximalBy[]` function? I have tried looking around and from what I can decipher is that `#` would mean you are taking the items in the list, `/.` is replace, and `_.` is blank argument. So you are taking the item in the list and replacing the `f1'[y] I E^(I x)` with whatever is in front of the `x` by `b/I` and then the `MaximalBy[]`returns the item in the lisst which has the highest value of all these replacements. Is this correct? The only thing I couldn't decipher was what the `&` does at the end.

Comment: Your analysis is correct. `# /. _. E^(b_. x) -> b/I &` is an [anonymous function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and the `&` sign marks the end of the function. This function takes something of the form $a e^{b x}$ and replaces it by $b/i$.

Comment: One more question, I actually ran into a problem when calculating terms that have `E^(0 I x)`. In my original expression, I have terms like `g2''[y] E^(0 I x)` where I have to use `HoldForm@` to keep the `E^(0 I x)` otherwise Mathematica evaluates this to 1. When comparing terms like `-f1[y] I E^(I x)` and `g2''[y] E^(0 I x)`, the function `MaximalBy[]` returns `g2''[y] E^(0 I x)` and `MinimalBy[]` returns `-f1[y] I E^(I x)` where it should return the opposite. I have tried `ReleaseHold[]` in many places to see how it would affect the output but no luck.

Comment: I can make a separate question if you would like so you can get the credit for the answer.

Comment: @CarlosVilleda see update using `Exponent`.

Comment: You are awesome.